# Does snowflake support filtering based on value of a string column in multi table insert?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a source table and multiple target tables, based on the value of a column it goes to the specified target table. Also rows are appended to the source table continuously via kafka+kafka connect. I create a stream on the source table and consume the stream with a multi table insert. Below is the sample code of what I'm trying to do :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA TEST_SCHEMA_2;
USE SCHEMA TEST_SCHEMA_2;


CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
    CustId int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE BLRCUST (
    CustId int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE NYCUST (
    CustId int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM CUST_STREAM on TABLE CUSTOMERS;

SELECT * FROM CUST_STREAM; -- should be empty

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS values 
(26743,'jon','snow','db 46 ajd. shd','ny'),
(3647,'karl','drogo','db 46 ajd. shd','blr'),
(475,'lores','tyrel','db 46 ajd. shd','ny'),
(5378,'cersi','lan','db 46 ajd. shd','blr');


SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS; -- display customers 


SELECT * FROM BLRCUST; -- empty
SELECT * FROM NYCUST; -- empty


SELECT * FROM CUST_STREAM; -- shopuld be same as customers

INSERT ALL
WHEN CITY='ny' THEN
    INTO NYCUST(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS) VALUES(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS)
WHEN CITY='blr' THEN
    INTO BLRCUST(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS) VALUES(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS)
SELECT CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS FROM CUST_STREAM WHERE metadata$action ='INSERT';
```

The last INSERT ALL statement fails with :

```
SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 5 invalid identifier 'CITY'
```

But if I replace the last block with :

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN CUSTID < 4000 THEN
    INTO NYCUST(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS) VALUES(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS)
WHEN CUSTID > 4000 THEN
    INTO BLRCUST(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS) VALUES(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS)
SELECT CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS FROM CUST_STREAM WHERE metadata$action ='INSERT';
```

It successfully inserts to the target tables. Is this a limitation with snowflake ?
Is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supported, but the column used in `WHEN` condition has to be visible(defined at the SELECT column list)

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN CITY='ny' THEN
    INTO NYCUST(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS) 
    VALUES(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS)
WHEN CITY='blr' THEN
    INTO BLRCUST(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS) 
    VALUES(CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS)
SELECT CUSTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRESS, CITY  -- here!
FROM CUST_STREAM 
WHERE metadata$action ='INSERT';
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
On a side note, if I have multiple city tables (~1k) is there a way to loop through this? Since the source table is a stream  it gets consumed after one iteration.